# Div is expanding instantly instead of over time?

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, angular-material

My div is expanding immediately after clicking my trigger rather than happening over time... Why is this, and how can I fix it?

html

```
<div class="card" #panel [ngClass]="{heightChange: panel.isExpanded}">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="itemName">Some text goes here</div>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!panel.isExpanded" (click)="panel.isExpanded=true">edit</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="panel.isExpanded" (click)="panel.isExpanded=false">cancel</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.card {
  background: white;
  padding: 12px;
  justify-items: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

mat-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.heightChange {
  height: 150px;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/height-expansion-test)

Comment: You can't transtion from `auto` to a set number. You need to define a start and end height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `height` property to your `div.card` class for the initial height.

And then Add another class named `div.card.heightChange` with the new height. `transition` only for `height` instead of all.

Change your CSS Classes to this:

```
div.card {
  background: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  justify-items: center;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

div.card.heightChange {
  height: 150px;
}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/height-expansion-test-bu77s7?file=src/app/app.component.css) for your ref.

Comment: I had done that in a previous attempt but it hadn't worked. Thank you for the working blitz :-)